# Rest API call result is not rendering in react native, how to fix that?

Tags: react-native, api, axios

I have an existing React native component in which I am rendering the coins avg price fetched from other functions in the same js file.

Today, I thought to add market value to it and used an API available online.

When I ran normally it is working but in the react, it is returning NAN.

My render function.

```
const renderCoin = ({ item, index }) => {
    console.log("---Inside render coin---" + item.text);
    let { averagePrice, totalCost, totalCount } = orderListData(
      item.text,
      userID,
      orders
    );
    let marketPrice = goForAxios(item.text);
    console.log(`${item.text} = ${marketPrice}`);
    return (
      <View style={[styles1.rowFront, { flexDirection: "row" }]}>
        <TouchableWithoutFeedback
          onPress={() =>
            props.navigation.navigate("Orders", {
              coin: item.text,
              userID: userID,
            })
          }
          style={{ flex: 1 }}
        >
          <Text>
            {item.text} {round(averagePrice)} {round(totalCost)}{" "}
            {round(totalCount)} {marketPrice}
          </Text>
        </TouchableWithoutFeedback>
        <TouchableOpacity
          onPress={() => onDeleteCoin(item.id)}
          style={{ flex: 1 }}
        >
          <Icon name={"trash"} size={30} color="#900" />
        </TouchableOpacity>
      </View>
    );
  };
```

And the function used to call the rest API.

```
const goForAxios = async (coin) => {
    

    const response = await axios.get(
      `https://min-api.cryptocompare.com/data/price?fsym=${coin}&tsyms=INR`
    );
    console.log(response.data.INR.toString());
    return response.data.INR.toString();
  };
```

Please suggest an alternative if my approach itself is wrong.

Answer (score 0):

The function `goForAxios` returns a Promise. So you can't render the value until the Promise Resolved.

How about create a new State and update it after you get the API response back?

```js
const RenderCoin = ({ item, index }) => {

    console.log("---Inside render coin---" + item.text);
    let { averagePrice, totalCost, totalCount } = orderListData(
      item.text,
      userID,
      orders
    );

    // new state to keep the response
    const [marketPrice, setMarketPrice] = useState(0);
    
    // make api request when the component mounts
    useEffect(()=> {
      (async () => {
        const marketPrice = await goForAxios(item.text);
        setMarketPrice(marketPrice);
      })();
    }, []);
    
 
    return (
      ....
    )
```

Comment: There will be multiple coins to fetch and I thought to call this function as you can see I am calling that in rendering let marketPrice = goForAxios(item.text); So, if I set state, it will rerender the page multiple time right and may cause calling this again. Also, I kept await in the function, why it is still returning Promise?

Comment: Tried your code and got this error: Error: Invalid hook call. Hooks can only be called inside of the body of a function component. This could happen for one of the following reasons:
1. You might have mismatching versions of React and the renderer (such as React DOM)
2. You might be breaking the Rules of Hooks
3. You might have more than one copy of React in the same app
 My code I have kept here, can you check please: https://codeshare.io/AdZByw

Comment: Even though you use await in goForAxios function, the RenderCoin function won't await for the response because RenderCoin is not async function...

goForAxios is returning promise.

Comment: And yes, you can only use hooks in Components. That's why I turned your renderCoin into `R`enderCoin (make the first letter capitalized) so that React could see it as a Component.

Comment: Still same issue, I changed as per your suggestion. https://codeshare.io/X8AXel

Comment: `NaN` basically means that you did a wrong math.  So the problem may not be in the API call but the calculation parts such as `{round(averagePrice)} {round(totalCost)}`.

Comment: the nan is for {marketPrice} the api call one. THe average and total are different fields , not related to this api and they are showing correctly